# How to affect all h2 tags inside a specific div id and with inner divs

Tags: html, css

I have this tricky problem in which I wanted to have all of my h2 tags inherit the CSS styles. I can't do it globally since it will affect some of my component's CSS styles. I had to specifically separate a CSS file in order to achieve this. Here's the following html output:

```
<div id="center">
    <h2>Sample center h2</h2>
    <div id="secondDiv">
        <h2>Sample secondDiv h2</h2>
        <div id="thirdDiv">
             <h2>Sample thirdDiv h2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this current solution where I did below:

```
#center h2 {
   text-align: center;
}

#center > div > h2 {
   text-align: center;
}

#center > div > div > h2 {
   text-align: center;
}
```

I think it is quite tedious and the sample inner divs have dynamic IDs in my real application. I wanted to affect all the h2 tags with maybe a single css line of code? Thanks!

Comment: You first CSS rule above will affect all 'h2' tags which are descendants of 'center'.  You do not need any more rules.

Comment: Are you needing all those nestings because some of the inner divs change the settings that you want inherited from the top one? If you make a runnable snippet we will be able to help more. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @petern0691 I tried only using the first CSS rule, but I didn't know why it is not affecting the inner h2 tags.

Comment: @AHaworth alright, I'll try to create a snippet.

Comment: You must be doing something else other than you have shown above, because the first rule works for me.

Comment: You can probably use the `is()` selector to write à single selector if you need to overwrite rules somewhere else in your css. `#center :is(h2,div>h2,div>div>h2) {text-align :center ;}` . Depends on your real situation.

Comment: Seems like I've been doing good. Thanks for the comments! The first CSS rule above was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was the first CSS rule I wrote. Thanks for the help!

```
#center h2 {
   text-align: center;
}
```